# Using Realm Swift with initializers throws constant errors

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Xcode 7.1 and Swift 2.1 with latest Realm Swift 0.96.2

I created a model class for Realm but it is constantly throwing errors about inits.  I understand initializers to an extent for subclasses but I can't wrap my head around this and why it fails.  Here's the class I made:

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class Boxes: Object {

    dynamic var precessor: String = "B";
    dynamic var id: Int = 0;
    dynamic var boxNumber: String {
        return "\(precessor) \(id)";  //computed property
    }
    dynamic var boxDescription: String? = "";
    dynamic var brand: String? = "";
    dynamic let dateCreated: NSDate
    dynamic var dateUpdated: NSDate?
    dynamic var photo: UIImage?
    dynamic var tags: NSArray? = [];

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id";  //sets primary key of the model
    }

    init(precessor: String, id: Int, description: String, brand: String, dateCreated: NSDate, dateUpdated: NSDate) {
        self.precessor = precessor;
        self.boxDescription = description;
        self.brand = brand;
        self.dateUpdated = dateUpdated;
        self.dateCreated = dateCreated;

        super.init();
    }
}
```

This won't build when I try and it tells me:

```
'required' initializer 'init()' must be provided by subclass of 'Object'
```

And that I need this line added:

```
required init() {
        fatalError("init() has not been implemented")
    }
```

That satiates the compiler enough to let me build the project.  However when I run the project, it always errors out and give me the fatalError line in the output.  I know it's doing this as a last resort initializer but I can't figure out why.

Is this related to a super initializer I'm missing somewhere?  I'm relatively new to swift but I can get my initializers to work if I don't subclass my class with `Object`

Comment: I think you need to check the docs for realm regarding what you can and can't do with properties in your `Object` subclass. e.g. I don't think it's going to support `UIImage` or `NSArray`...

Comment: I'll double check, but I was told CoreData wouldn't hold a `UIImage` and recommended using Realm instead.  Thanks!

Comment: You probably need to convert images to `NSData` first as that is supported. Although "NSData properties cannot hold data exceeding 16MB in size."

Comment: Once I got passed the init error I received runtime errors for those exact issues (the array and image).  For now I've removed the array and changed the image to NSData.  Thanks for the information and help!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are required to implement `init()` but Xcode doesn't know how to implement if for you so it puts in `fatalError("init() has not been implemented")` to remind you to implement it.

You probably just want to call super. So:

```
required init() {
    super.init()
}
```

Comment: This should be correct answer I think. It is also possible to add default values to all your properties to fix this problem.

Comment: I'm no realm expert, but I don't think `dynamic let dateCreated : NSDate` is valid. From the docs "All property types except for List and RealmOptional must be declared as dynamic var"

Comment: This did indeed work but i ultimately had to add defaults to all my properties or I would get a `property self.xxx not initialized at super.init call`.  Thank you so much! I guess I have a lot more to read about initializers.

Comment: this does not work in my case, could you have a look here?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36824202/realmswift-initializers-xcode-fix-it-keeps-getting-it-wrong